# Python Esoteric Interpreter using Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, esoteric-languages

I've continued messing with the ZOMBIE esoteric language, and the interpreter I've been using is throwing some errors.

The interpreter is here: http://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Marinus/ZOMBIE_interpreter

The specification is here: http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/zombie.html

I am using Terminal on a Mac.
When I run the Hello World program though the interpreter,

```
HelloWorld is a zombie
summon
task SayHello
    say "Hello World!"
animate
animate
```

Terminal says-

```
HelloWorld is a zombie
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I believe there is a problem with the syntax-recognizing regular expressions in the interpreter, but I have no experience with them.
Here is the code I believe is to blame:

```
comment_re = re.compile("\{.*?\}", re.DOTALL)
declaration_re = re.compile(r'([A-Za-z0-9_\-]*?)\s+is\s+an?\s+(zombie|enslaved undead|' + \
                        r'ghost|restless undead|vampire|free-willed undead' + \
                        r'|demon|djinn)', re.I)

task_re = re.compile("task\s+([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)", re.I)
remember_re = re.compile("remember\s+(.*)", re.I)

string_re = re.compile('".*?"')
integer_re = re.compile('[\-0-9\.]+')
```

Sorry I can't be more specific... any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just fine for me:

```
temp $ python zombie.py zombie.z 
Hello World!
```

I copied the source of the interpretter directly from the link you posted for the interpreter and saved it as `zombie.py` in the current directory (`~/temp`, although that's irrelevant).  Then I copied the source of the zombie HelloWorld program directly from your post and saved it as `zombie.z` (again in the current directory).  It prints `Hello World!` as I'm assuming it is supposed to...

(python2.7, Mac OS X 10.5.8)

The SyntaxError leads me to believe that you're trying to run the `zombie.z` (or whatever you called it) from python directly e.g. `python zombie.z` or something like that ... That won't work.

---

As an aside, I think it's interesting that both myself and the poster from your previous question (independently) choose `.z` as the extension of `zombie` source files.  Must just be the natural choice...

Comment: You are right - the only two occurences of "syn" in the interpreter are in the comments.

Comment: @JanDvorak -- Thanks.  I think I'm right too, although I'm not sure what "syn" has to do with it ... Could you explain?

Comment: @JanDvorak -- Ahh, I see.  So you're saying that the zombie interpreter couldn't write that message since the string `'SyntaxError'` doesn't appear anywhere.  I understand.

Comment: I was indeed attempting to run the file directly from python... Tried what you suggested and it works fine now. Many thanks!

Comment: For the record: I chose `.zom` for my files.